# How to remove certain comments from a json file? (/*)

Tags: python, json

I have about 500 json files with comments in them. Trying to update a field on the json file with a new value, throws an error. I managed to use commentjson to remove strings like this // some text and the json file updates and throws no errors.

But there is about 100 json files with comments like this:

```
  /*

   1. sometext.
        i. sometext
        ii. sometext 
   2. sometext

  */
```

Commentjson just crashes when /* exists. If I remove /* and run the code, it will work and update and remove any //.
How can I write some code to manage /* and all text between /* */?

This is my current code that can remove //

```
with open(f"{i['Location']}\\{file_name}",'r') as f:
    json_info = commentjson.load(f) #Gets info from the json file
    json_info['password'] = password

    with open(f"{i['location_Daily']}\\{file_name}",'w') as f:
        commentjson.dump(json_info,f,indent = 4) #updates the password   
        print("updated")
```

Comment: Why you want to remove them?

Comment: @OlvinRoght Comments are not even valid JSON, so most JSON parsers will blow up trying to read these files (and whoever created them should get a stern talking to ;)

Comment: @Iguananaut, there're JSON parsers which support JSON5 standard.

Comment: @Iguananaut: The `commentjson` package does support comments: *commentjson (Comment JSON) is a Python package that helps you create JSON files with Python and JavaScript style inline comments*. Just not this style.

Comment: I need to remove these because when I try to update an value that contents comments, my code throws an error and wont update. So far I've managed to handle the comments but the /* is causing issues now.

Comment: *Just not this style* Right, so it's a good reason to want to remove them (and in general so that standard JSON parsers can read the files).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options:

- Read the whole file into a string, then use a regular expression to pre-process the text. E.g.:

  ```
  with open(...) as f:
      json_text = f.read()
  # remove everything from '/*' to '*/' as long as it is either
  # - a '*' character that is *not* followed by '/'
  # - any character that is not '*'
  without_comments = re.sub(r"/\*(?:\*(?!/)|[^*])*\*/", "", json_text)
  json_info = commentjson.loads(without_comments)
  ```

  Note that this approach is not going to work if there are also JSON strings with the `/*` and `*/` inside of them. A regex is not a JSON parser.

- try to update the parser that the `commonjson` project uses to parse out JSON. Looking at [the project source code](https://github.com/vaidik/commentjson/blob/c8678f4d0282368b58c84b1934eee99370892987/commentjson/commentjson.py#L26-L59), they use the [Lark parsing library](https://lark-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), so you *could* monkey patch the module with additional grammar.

  I note that the main branch already has a grammar rule defining multi-line comments:

  ```
  COMMENT: "/*" /(.|\\n)+?/ "*/"
         | /(#|\\/\\/)[^\\n]*/
  ```

  but that is not yet part of their release. You can, however, re-use that rule:

  ```
  from commentjson import commentjson as implementation
  from lark.reconstruct import Reconstructor

  serialized = implementation.parser.serialize()
  for tok in serialized["parser"]["lexer_conf"]["tokens"]:
      if tok["name"] != "COMMENT":
          continue
      if tok["pattern"]["value"].startswith("(#|"):
          # only supports `#` or `//` comments, add block comments
          tok["pattern"]["value"] = r'(?:/\*(?:\*(?!/)|[^*])*\*/|(#|\/\/)[^\n]*)'
      break

  implementation.parser = implementation.parser.deserialize(serialized, None, None)
  ```

  I used my own regex in that grammar update rather than the version used by the project.
- Find a different library to parse the input. There are several options that claim to support parsing JSON with the same syntax:

  - [jstyleson](https://github.com/linjackson78/jstyleson)
  - [pyjson5](https://github.com/dpranke/pyjson5)
  - [jsoncomment](https://pypi.org/project/jsoncomment/)

  I have not tried any of these nor have anything to say about their usability or performance.

Comment: @LewisGreen: I've added code to update the `commentjson` parser to support block comments directly.

Answer (score 6):

You can use another library such as [json5](https://pypi.org/project/json5/) or [pyjson5](https://pypi.org/project/pyjson5/) or anything that supports [JSON5](https://json5.org/)

```
import json5
import pyjson5

data = '''
{
    "something": [
        ["any"],
        ["thing", "here", 10]    // This is comment 1
    ],
    /* While this
    is
    comment 2 */
    "car": [
        ["and", "another", "here"], /* Last comment */
    ]
}
'''

print(json5.loads(data))
print(pyjson5.loads(data))
```

**Output**

```
$ python3 script.py 
{'something': [['any'], ['thing', 'here', 10]], 'car': [['and', 'another', 'here']]}
{'something': [['any'], ['thing', 'here', 10]], 'car': [['and', 'another', 'here']]}
```

Comment: It's important to notice that `pyjson5` is **much faster** than `json5` and significantly faster than pure python `json`. Check: [Performance](https://pyjson5.readthedocs.io/en/latest/performance.html) section of `pyjson5` docs; *Known Issues* section in [`json5`](https://pypi.org/project/json5/) project description.